# MATLAB and Arduino communication

Tags: serial, matlab

I have to send from MATLAB to Arduino a char line 'S' to start the Arduino program and send back values from a sensor. 
This is my MATLAB code

```cpp
clear;
delete(instrfind);
s = serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem1411','BaudRate',9600, 'Terminator','CR/LF');
fopen(s);
fprintf(s,'%s\n','S');

t = 0;
valor=zeros(1,100);
tiempo=zeros(1,100);
fid=fopen('resultats.txt','w');
for i=1:100         
    a = fscanf(s,'%d');
    wd = 0.0189*a - 14.499;
    valor(i)=wd;
    tiempo(i)=t;
    fprintf(fid,'%3d %6d\n', wd,t);  
    t = t+200;
end
plot(tiempo,valor);
fclose(fid);
fclose(s);
```

and my Arduino code is this

```cpp
int outValue = 0;
unsigned long time;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (Serial.available() <= 0 || Serial.read() != 'S') {
    Serial.println("Send 'S' to start");
    delay(200); }
  Serial.println("Starting measurement");
}
void loop() {
  outValue = analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println(outValue);
  delay(200);
}
```

the problem is that when I use the MATLAB code it send an 'S' and it makes Arduino start sending values back, but Arduino does not do that and just sending the while loop again and again.

Is the problem in the MATLAB code when it send the char 'S'?

Comment: Could you try delaying for a couple of seconds between `fopen(s);` and `fprintf(s,'%s\n','S');`?